# MySQL insert or update on duplicate

Tags: php, sql

I was curious if it was bad practice to, instead of having a separate ADD and UPDATE function, simply have an INSERT and UPDATE on DUPLICATE KEY function. This would work for me because I can UPDATE the same columns that I would ADD. I just wonder if this short cut is a bad idea for any reason.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you need to insert some Data and you don't know, if it already exist, it is a good idea.

If you already know that this Data is availible or not (Because you need this in your Software), you should do a simple `UPDATE` or `INSERT`.

Comment: Well the user has two options: Add or Update. Therefore the system always knows if it is new or old. But because the forms are the exact same for Add and Update, I was wondering if it is OK to use the same SQL statement. INSERT .. or .. UPDATE